# Auth to google API with API-Key instead of OAuth 2.0

Tags: postman, google-calendar-api

In https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/list?apix=true#auth

I can see that I can use OAuth2 and API key to authenticate for the `calendarList` endpoints:

[image]

My first test with postman and OAuth2 works perfect: I get the JSON List of all calendars of the authenticated user

Now I test the endpoint with authentication over API key.

I create the API key and enabled the calendar for this API key:

[image]

**Problem:**

I've tested it with postman and `Auth-Type=ApiKey` and with parameter `key=MYAPIKEY`, but I always get error

> 401 "Request is missing required authentication credential"

[image]

Does anyone have a (postman) example to access the Google calendard API with an API key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API keys are only used to access public data not private user data.

In order to use an api key with postman you would simply take the rquest and add key=YourKEY on the end

The following is a good example of this but unfortunately there is currently an issue with API keys and public calendars. Requiring authorization instead of just an api key[194427607](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194427607)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.danish%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

You are not going to be able to use calendar list without being authorized  [calendarlist.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/list) states in the documentation that you must be authorized as its private user data.

[image]